# How to delete multiple nodes by specific ID using Cypher

Tags: jdbc, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to optimize this cypher query.
I am using neo4j-jdbc

For a given source node and list of target nodes I would like to remove the relationship("follow) between them).

Right now I only found a way to execute them on each transaction:

for example:

source node: 34 and targetNodes: 777

execute:

```
MATCH (p1:users)-[r:follow]->(p2:users)
WHERE p1.userId='34' and p2.userId='777' and
delete r
```

java neo4j-jdbc code:

```
 public void deleteNodes(String sourceUserId, Set<String> userIdsList) {
        try {
            conn = neo4jDataSource.openConnection();
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            newUserDistanceList.forEach(user -> {
                try {
                    this.deleteRelationship(sourceUserId, user.getUserId());
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Error deleting relationship for sourceNode=" + sourceUserId + ", targetNode=" + user.getUserId(), e);
                }
            });
            conn.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error deleting relationship for sourceNode=" + sourceUserId, e);
        } finally {
            neo4jDataSource.closeConnection(conn);
        }
    }


 public void createNodeAndSetRelationship(String sourceUserId, String targetUserId) throws SQLException {
        String deleteUserStmnt =
 "MATCH (p1:users)-[r:follow]->(p2:users) "+
    "WHERE p1.userId=~{1} and p2.userId=~{2} and "+
    "delete r";            
        try (final PreparedStatement ps1 = conn.prepareStatement(deleteUserStmnt)) {
            ps1.setString(1, sourceUserId);
            ps1.setString(2, targetUserId);
            ps1.executeQuery();
        }
    }
```

How would you optimize this into one query to include it all? is it even possible?

*P.S please add any other notes about this code if you find them helpful.

Response to comments:

I added my nodes this way:

```
MERGE (p1:C10{userId:'1'})
MERGE (p2:C10{userId:'2'})
MERGE (p3:C10{userId:'3'})
MERGE (p1)-[r1:follow]->(p2) 
MERGE (p1)-[t1:follow]->(p3)
```

When executing the delete query nothing is being deleted:

```
MATCH (user1:C10 {userId: 1})-[r:follow]->(users:C10) WHERE
 users.userId in [3, 2] DELETE r
```

- userId is unique property on each node

Any idea?

Thank you,
ray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Query

Let's create some data to test that our query will work.

```
CREATE (user1:User {id: "1"})
CREATE (user2:User {id: "2"})
CREATE (user3:User {id: "3"})
CREATE (user1)-[:FOLLOW]->(user2)
CREATE (user1)-[:FOLLOW]->(user3)
```

How our data looks right now:
[image: data]

Let's write query to delete `:FOLLOW` relationship from between user1 and user2 and user3:

```
MATCH (user1:User {id: "1"})-[r:FOLLOW]->(users:User)
WHERE users.id in ["2", "3"]
DELETE r
```

Now relationship's are gone:
[image: result]

Good luck :)

**Note:** this works with strings too.
**Note2:** you should check that [index](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-schema-index.html) (or event [constraint](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-constraints.html)) exists for your `userId` property on `:user` nodes.

### neo4j-jdbc

Code sample for `neo4j-jdbc` that does work:

```
Class.forName("org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474/");
String removeRelationships = "MATCH (user1:User {id: {1}})-[r:FOLLOW]->(users:User) " +
        "WHERE users.id in {2} " +
        "DELETE r";
try (final PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(removeRelationships)) {
    stmt.setObject(1, "1");
    stmt.setObject(2, new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
        add("2");
        add("3");
    }});
    stmt.executeQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detail answer. however it didnt work. I want to delete users by userId which is property on each node(it's indexed as unique) . I edited my answer please look at it

Comment: Change numbers to strings in query. I used numbers for example. In your case -  WHERE users.id IN ['2', '3']

Comment: And lookup should use string too - MATCH (user1:C10 {userId: '1'}]

Comment: that worked on cypher. but how you modify that to work using neo4j-jdbc statement?  I switched into List<String>.. but didnt work:  stmt.setObject(2, new ArrayList<String>(){{
                add("2");
                add("3");
            }});

Comment: Check that strings are used for all id's - '1', '2', '3'

Comment: That worked. thank you! is it possible using neo4j-jdbc when setting the array object - instead of passing List of Strings to pass List of pojos and than specify taking specific field (which is string field) for the final execution ? (hope you got me;) else ill need to convert my array of pojo's into array of Strings before execution

Comment: Nope. In Java 8 you can use streams. Pseudocode - listOfPojos.stream().map(User::getId)

Comment: Yes. Gotcha. btw: Do you recommend using connection-pool with neo4j-jdbc?

Comment: Yeap. It's JDBC adapter. All recommendations that applies on any adapter works for Neo4j too.